# Jelastic Mongo local db connection

Tags: mongodb, jelastic

I've create Mongo replica set.
Now I need to connect to Mongo `local` db to see oplog. But I can't create prope user for this. I've tried:

```
db.createUser({ user: "opadmin1", pwd: "pass", roles:[{ role: "clusterManager", db: "admin"}]})
db.createUser({ user: "opadmin2", pwd: "pass", roles:[{ role: "clusterManager", db: "local"}]})
db.createUser({ user: "opadmin3", pwd: "evalola", roles:["clusterManager"]})
db.createUser({ user: "opadmin4", pwd: "pass", roles:[{ role: "readWrite", db: "local"}]})
```

When I try to connect like `mongodb://opadmin2@[mongo-env]/local` I get auth error with code 18 every time.

Answer (score 1):

you can get this error in the case of wrong credentials or incorrect permissions for reading the directory. I think the best way to analyze this to contact support of your Jelastic provider, because  it's too hard to say exactly what is going on in your environment.